# Execute other python script when django server is started

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and other python script which is a ZMQ socket which continuously listens for message to perform some operation, ZMQ server script is an independent script which for now runs as `python zmq_server.py` in a terminal or cmd.

What I am trying to do is start the ZMQ server script when `python manage.py runserver` is called to start the django server.

I did some digging but found nothing related to this, is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You could try putting `import zmq_server` in your settings or views and see if that does it

Comment: It is executing when I put it in settings.py, but I have to create a seperate thread or async process to execute that zmq_server script. will it be any issue if it is a seperate thread?

Comment: I think it should be fine

Comment: It works. It looks fine as it is working as expected. Thanks rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run any script when your Django server starts by importing it in your `settings.py` at the top like this:

```
import zmq_server
```

Normally that's what you'd do for a script you're going to use in your project, but if you just want it to get executed you can do it like that as well.

Comment: You are technically correct but settings.py gets executed twice, so my zmq_server throws an error that address already in use because it tries to bind the socket twice. Is there any other way to execute my server only once?

Comment: @VatsalChavda could you use `sys.modules` to get a list of already imported modules?

Comment: @VatsalChavda Have you tried putting the import statement in your views?

Comment: @VatsalChavda In my project the settings.py only gets loaded once, but I have seen it get loaded twice. It may be that you are importing your settings.py somewhere else in your project